# Como adicionar opção de imprimir no API do Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Recentemente desenvolvi um script que gera rotas a partir das marcações no API do google maps, eu gostaria de adicionar a opção de imprimir essa rota, ou seja, o mapa. Notei que no site oficial do Google Maps tem a opção de imprimir e ele gera uma imagem fixa para ser impressa, e não o mapa "manipulável".

Qualquer idéia que seja diferente mas com o mesmo resultado final será bem vinda e de grande ajuda.

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Como assim, você quer "manipular" a imagem na visualização par impressão? Coloque seu código, para entendermos melhor oq ue você precisa.

Comment: Na verdade não preciso manipular, eu só quero gerar uma imagem a partir do resultado retornado pelo mapa, para imprimir. Ou então um próprio botão do API que faça isso, mas desconheço. Enfim, preciso imprimir o mapa, já tentei Ctrl + P, mas corta, então transformando em imagem seria possível redimensionar para caber na página. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia, segue um link que me ajudou a fazer o que você deseja fazer, ele irá ensinar a pegar o mapa e criar uma imagem não manipulável pronta para imprimir [https://fazcertoquefunciona.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/html5-geolocalizacao/](https://fazcertoquefunciona.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/html5-geolocalizacao/)